# xml utf-8 encoding error in java

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8

The code looks like this:

```
XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

        XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory
                .createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"));

        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEvent end = eventFactory.createDTD("\n");
        XMLEvent tab = eventFactory.createDTD("\t");

        StartDocument startDocument = eventFactory.createStartDocument(
                "UTF-8", "1.0");
        eventWriter.add(startDocument);
...
```

When I open the xml file, google chrome says "encoding error" at the first utf-8 character, and if I look the xml code, it looks like:

```
?xml version="1.0"?
```

there is no encoding part in it...

Do you have any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: UTF-8 is the default; it doesn't need to be specified. How are you opening the file in Chrome? (Locally, or via a web server? Perhaps the server is messing things up?)

Comment: A missing `encoding="..."` defaults to UTF-8. So no worry. You might however look whether there is a BOM character as first character of the file, this is a (generally deprecated) Unicode zero width space. You will need a tool for seeing it. You could try deleting beginning chars.

Comment: I was not using a web server. Now this problem got solved, so I can focus on the others :) thanks for the fast replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding here

```
.createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"), "UTF-8");
```

otherwise it uses the platform default

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding

```
XMLEvent end = eventFactory.createDTD("\n");
```

is probably not what you meant. A DTD is a text declaring entities and tags; XML in a non-XML script.
Try removing them.